# How can I make an app access a website to get information?

Tags: android, html

I want to make an app that can access a website and extract information from it. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in control of the website I recommend you to take a look on JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

Simple case is just openning an HTTP Connection to the site and then redirecting the data to an input buffer and reading everything. Here is an example:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpGet()`. Here is an Android example:

http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache HTTP that's included on Android.